# run from Shell R function with parameter, that contains quotes

Tags: r, shell, quotes

Suppose, I have function:

```
 my_function<-function(string) return(string)
```

When I run it from R:

```
>my_function('string"with"quotes')
[1] "string\"with\"quotes"
```

It works well. But when I try to run this function from Shell:

```
  R -e "source('./my_function.R'); my_function('string"with"quotes')"
```

It fails with error, because shell can't deal with quotes.

Is there any solution for this problem?

P.S. I need to run this function directly from Shell.

Comment: Why not escape the inner double quotes using `\"`?

Comment: Because it is very long string of json, that contains many quotes and brackets. Thank you, for suggestion.

Comment: you could read your string from a file or stdin, then supply it to your function

Comment: As I've already written, I need to run function directly from Shell

Comment: did you find a solution to this ? i m in almost the same situation myself..

Comment: @Raghav, As I remember, I haven't found directly solution, except of what was meant before with escaping...